# Where do I find the callback function prototypes for the various signals in GTK?

Tags: gtk

I've just started learning GTK+.  But, I'm having trouble finding essentials in the documentation.  Namely the callback prototypes for signals like "activate" on menu's.
I understand there might be a standard callback.  But this isn't clear.

Is this the correct prototype for a callback for a menu selection?

```
// Is this correct?  It does appear to work.  But I don't want to be sure so as to avoid any corruption
static void menu_select(GtkMenu* menu, int item)
{
  printf("menu_activate: %d\n", item);
}


void build_menu()
{
  // ...
  login = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Login");
  // ...
  separator = gtk_separator_menu_item_new();
  quit = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Exit");

  // ...
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(login), "activate", G_CALLBACK(menu_select), GINT_TO_POINTER(0));
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(quit), "activate", G_CALLBACK(menu_select), GINT_TO_POINTER(1));
}
```

Comment: In the documentation. Each page on a class has a section listing the signals; each signal has its own section that begins with the proper prototype. Which version of GTK+ is this? And yes, your code is wrong: the last parameter will always be of type `gpointer`; you will need to use `GPOINTER_TO_INT()` in your callback function to get the `int` back out properly. (What you have now will break [on environments where an int is not pointer-sized](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/31/363790.aspx). It's unfortunate that there isn't type checking for GCallbacks, but c'est la C.)

Comment: @andlabs - Thanks.  However, for GTK Menu it doesn't show the "activate" signal in the doc page I'm looking at.  https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenu.html#gtk-menu-new  I guess it's at the different level?  where is the activate prototype for menus found?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong class; you want [GtkMenuItem](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuItem.html#GtkMenuItem-activate) instead.

Comment: Thanks... makes sense now.